# Can \subref and xr work together?

Tags: subcaption, xr

With `xr` I can cross-reference labels in another document. With `subcaption` I can refer to subfigures (or similar). But if I try to combine them both, it seems they don't recognise each other:

a.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\section{Main}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  A
  \caption{}\label{fig:A}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
  B
  \caption{}\label{fig:B}
  \end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
See \ref{fig}, panels \subref{fig:A} and \subref{fig:B}.
\end{document}
```

b.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[A-]{a}
\begin{document}
\section{Main}
See \ref{A-fig}, panels \subref{A-fig:A} and \subref{A-fig:B}.
\end{document}
```

After compiling `a.tex`, `b.tex` says:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `sub@A-fig:A' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sub@A-fig:B' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.
```

If I change the `\subref{A-fig:A}` to `\ref{A-sub@fig:B}`, it seems to work as expected. Can the definition of `\subref` be modified to make it compatible with `xr`?

Comment: Probably, but it would still use `\ref{A-sub@fig:A}` internally. Easiest solution would be to give `\subref` two arguments, as in `\subref[A-]{fig:A}`.

Answer (score 2):

well the problem is that both add a prefix to the label name.

You could change the xr prefix to a suffix

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\XR@test{\XR@prefix#2}{#2\XR@prefix}{}{\fail}
\externaldocument[-A]{a}
\begin{document}
\section{Main}
See \ref{fig-A}, panels \subref{fig:A-A} and \subref{fig:B-A}.
\end{document}
```

The alternative is to patch the subcaption commands (in both documents!) to switch to a suffix:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\subcaption@@label{sub@#2}{#2@sub}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\subcaption@ref{sub@#2}{#2@sub}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
```